# Suppress shiny output to console

Tags: r, shiny

I'm looking to suppress shiny output to the console. I am aware of the typical R methods of console suppression. For this issue when I run a system command a portion of the system response is posted to the console:

```
if(system("fuser -n tcp 8888 >/dev/null") == 0){
  output$serverStatusType <- renderText("Running...")
  return(TRUE)
} else {
  output$serverStatusType <- renderText("Stopped...")
  return(FALSE)
}

dataSvrStatusUpdate <- observe({
  invalidateLater(5000, session)
  svrCheck()
  return()
})
```

The console will return:

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:3563

8888/tcp:
8888/tcp:
8888/tcp:
....

I would like to stop this console output, I have tried invisible() no go.

Comment: Is the output you see maybe stderr? What if you redirect it: `2>&1 > /dev/null`?

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it...

```
system("fuser -n tcp 8888 >/dev/null 2>&1")
```

will send any response away to null. Certainly not an R or Shiny issues just my poor skills with scripting.

Thanks for the feedback.